# Where did I mess up this outer join?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to add 1 column from table "OP" to table "density".

```
SELECT density.*, OP.[OP %]
FROM density 
LEFT JOIN OP ON (density.[Billet Number] = OP.[Billet Number] 
             AND density.Specimen = OP.Specimen)
UNION
SELECT density.*,OP.[OP %]
FROM density 
RIGHT JOIN OP ON (density.Specimen = OP.Specimen 
           AND density.[Billet Number] = OP.[Billet Number])
WHERE density.Specimen IS NULL 
      AND density.[Billet Number] IS NULL;
```

OP has 12 rows, density has ~150. When I run the query, the column "OP %" is added to the table, but the 12 values are in new rows, not with "Specimen" and "Billet Number"

Comment: sounds like you want an INNER JOIN

Comment: Are there any rows of OP where density.[Specimen] and density.[Billet Number] match the values for OP.[Specimen] and OP.[Billet Number]?

Comment: @sigil the combination of OP.[Specimen] and OP.[Billet Number] matches 1 row in density.
So each row in OP has a corresponding row in density

Comment: Did those rows show up in your query results with the corresponding [OP %] value added?

Comment: If you're just trying to add the [OP %] column for each row of data in density then you don't need a UNION query, you can get rid of the RIGHT JOIN query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for a `UNION` or a `WHERE`. If you know the rows in `OP` match those in `Density` you can do an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT density.*, OP.[OP %]
FROM density 
INNER JOIN OP ON (density.[Billet Number] = OP.[Billet Number] 
             AND density.Specimen = OP.Specimen);
```

If it's possible that there are mismatches but you still need all of the rows from `density` (with missing values for `[OP %]` when there is no match), then use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT density.*, OP.[OP %]
FROM density 
LEFT JOIN OP ON (density.[Billet Number] = OP.[Billet Number] 
             AND density.Specimen = OP.Specimen);
```

Comment: That's a lot simpler than what I was trying to do. I want to add one more criteria, a field called [Billet Material]. I tried adding AND density.[Billet Material] = OP.[Billet Material to the end (moving the parentheses and colon as well) and a box pops up asking for a parameter. What causes this?

Comment: Never mind on that last question. One of the tables wasn't updated.